# Regex to limit the length between parenthesis

Tags: regex

Looking for a `regex` that would **limit** the length of characters inside of user input where parenthesis are used.

Example user input:

```
"this is an (test) example"
```

Now I want to limit `test` to only allow  5 characters.

Comment: this is a very easy task, what were your attempts?

Comment: You want to validate the whole string, or you want to get the parentesis that contains only with 5 symbols?
Basicaly "/\([a-z]{5}\)/" should work

Comment: Match up to the first five characters in a specific group, then replace the whole parenthesis with a back-reference to the grouped characters

Comment: @user2693928 I want to validate the whole string, as well as check the length between the parenthesis.

Comment: I guess you need `^\([^()]{0,5}\)$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
\(\w{1,5}\)
```

[Expalanation](https://regex101.com/r/sG5GMI/3)

1. ( matches the character
2. \w{1,5} matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
3. {1,5} Quantifier — Matches between 1 and 5 times(greedy)
4. ) matches the character ) literally